# Saving playlist file from application

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android application. I would like to save an m3u file from my application to a shared folder on the phone, in order to make it available to other applications (music player) and make it survive even if user removes my application.

This is what I tried to do:

```
String directory = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath();

File file = new File(directory, filename + ".m3u");
```

But it does not work, i get

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 FileName += "/filename+3gp";
```

Comment: I tried this:  String directory =
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(directory, filename + ".m3u");
boolean exist = file.createNewFile();
if(exist)
   FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filename + ".m3u");

and in AndroidManifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

but it gives me an exception on the filewriter call:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /my_playlist.m3u (Read-only file system).